# How to avoid duplicate password input to ssh hosts in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm writing a script to conduct some changes on server side.

```
for HOST in ${WORKER_HOSTS}; do
    echo ${HOST}
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${HOST} "doSomething"
done

Do something locally

for HOST in ${WORKER_HOSTS}; do
    echo ${HOST}
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${HOST} "doSomething"
done

Do something locally

for HOST in ${WORKER_HOSTS}; do
    echo ${HOST}
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${HOST} "doSomething"
done
```

Though I've set StrictHostKeyChecking to be no, it still asks me to conduct password input three times for the same host during execution.

Is there a way to avoid the duplicate input for password for the same hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ssh-agent` along with a public/private key pair with a passphrase. `ssh-agent` "unlocks" your private key for the duration of a user session after the passphrase is given once. Proper setup depends on your platform however so you will need to look for a tutorial.

StrictHostKeyChecking has nothing to do with passwords. It means checking whether the remote host is in the known_hosts and/or has changed identity since the last login. Having it on, and disabling known hosts entirely, is probably a bad idea.